# Regular expressions matching given string

Tags: regex, regular-language, automata

I had an exam and there was an ambiguous question that confused all the students. The question was: What is the regular expression that accepts the string `aaaabbbb`?

And the options were (we had to choose one option only):

1. `aa*bb*`
2. `a*b*`
3. `(a+b)*`
4. `(a+b)*(a+b)*`

I expected the answer to be `(a+b)*` as it the most general regular expression that accepts all the strings over the alphabet {a, b}.

Comment: Could you please use standard regular expression syntax or define the syntax you use? The use of `+` with and without `^` is very confusing.

Comment: ok, I modified it to aa* bb*

Comment: Do the whitespaces matter? `(a + b)* (a + b)*` Doesn't feel like a normal regex. Is this some kind of pseudo regex language?

Comment: no the whitespaces does not matter, I put the whitespaces becausse, if I don't put whitespaces the editor removes *, I don't know why

Comment: In that case every regex here passes the test for `aaaabbbb`, since most of the regex have the optional quatifier `*`

Comment: but we have to choose only one of them

Comment: @MarwanShaheen Wrap code in backticks (e.g. `\`aa*bb*\``) so that they are rendered as code and not Markdown.

Comment: @MarwanShaheen was there any side condition to be fulfilled (such as *strictest* / *most lax*)? Without a side condition, all RegExes presented are valid answers. With such a side condition, `L(aa*bb*)` is a subset of `L(a*b*)` which is a subset of `L((a+b)*) = L((a+b)*(a+b)*)`. If the "strictest" RegEx was asked for, you should have chosen `aa*bb*` then; both `(a+b)*` and `(a+b)*(a+b)*` are the most lax, recognizing the same language of `{a,b}*`.

Comment: no there was no side condition

Comment: What does `+` mean in the regular expression language you are using. There are many types of RegEx. For this sort of question we need to know which variety you are subing. Please read the description of [tag:regex].

Comment: where is the + . I have replaced it with aa*

Comment: There is a `+`  in (3) `(a+b)*` and (4) `(a+b)*(a+b)*`, also in *"I expected the answer to be `(a+b)*`"*.

Comment: I got you. + means OR

Comment: So, should  (3) `(a+b)*` should be interpreted as *zero or more occurences of (either an `a` or a `b`)*? In the RegExs use in many programming languages that would be written a `[ab]*`.

Comment: If the exam question was really presented like this, it was a really bad question. All four answers are correct. Option 3 and 4 match the same inputs (so the claim that 3 is the most general would also apply to 4), option 2 matches a subset of 3, and option 1 matches a subset of 2. The input `aaaabbbb` is in all these sets. The designer of this question should be ashamed.

Comment: *... as it the most general regular expression that accepts all the strings over the alphabet {a, b}."*: that's all very nice, but that was not the exam question. And even if this requirement (of being the most "general") *were* mentioned in the question, it would also apply to option 4.

Comment: I guess the question would be a better fit for https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ than for Stack Overflow. It is not about a programming problem. It is about regular expressions, but not in the programming sense, but in the theoretical computer science sense.